# creating and match token between two dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, match, token

**Update** So i have a textile with thousand of lines that looks like this

BRCA    A2ML1   Missense_Mutation   TCsA-A1-A0SO    A8K2U0  W408C

BRCA    A2ML1   Missense_Mutation   TCsA-A8-A08P    A8K2U0  R433H

BRCA    A2ML1   Missense_Mutation   TCsA-B6-A0WZ    A8K2U0  P1341L

I have written the code to capture the whole line and only 6th token (code below)
Right now I am trying to match the 6th token to its own line.

**What i hope to get as output** is that I am trying to write an output file that looks like this (This is just a couple of examples)

> A8K2U0 |START=1 END.....| R433H |BRCA  A2ML1   Missense_Mutation   TCsA-A8-A08P    A8K2U0  R433H

and same as other lines

> A8K2U0 |START=1 END.....| P1341L |BRCA A2ML1   Missense_Mutation   TCsA-B6-A0WZ    A8K2U0  P1341L

here is my code for the dictionary:

```
lookup = defaultdict(list) 
wholelookup = defaultdict(list)
wholeline = defaultdict(list)
mydata = open('file.txt')

for line in csv.reader(mydata, delimiter='\t'):
    code = re.match('[a-z](\d+)[a-z]', line[-1], re.I)
    if code:      
       lookup[line[-2]].append(code.group(1))
       wholelookup[line[-2]].append(code.group(0))
       s=' '.join(line)
       wholeline[line[-2]].append(s)
```

Comment: I formatted your code, but honestly, I still can't understand what you're asking here.  Could you try to clean this up a bit to make it a little more comprehensible?

Comment: @mgilson i just updated does that make sense?

Comment: no, it doesn't. where is the question? Whats the output? Why isn't the output correct?

Comment: @ColinDunklau so i want to know how to use if statement to test whether  A177T is in COADREAD ZNF271 Missense_Mutation MAAA-AA-3947 Q14591 A177T?

Comment: You're almost there... what do the fields represent?

Comment: @ColinDunklau what do you mean by field

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14362/discussion-between-chad-d-and-colin-dunklau)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question how do i use if statement to find out whether `A177T` is in `COADREAD ZNF271 Missense_Mutation MAAA-AA-3947 Q14591 A177T`?

Trivially:

```
test_string = 'A177T'
to_search = 'COADREAD ZNF271 Missense_Mutation MAAA-AA-3947 Q14591 A177T'
if test_string in to_search:
    print "found", test_string
```

Or with DSM's advice:

```
test_string = 'A177T'
to_search = 'COADREAD ZNF271 Missense_Mutation MAAA-AA-3947 Q14591 A177T'
if test_string in to_search.split(' '):
    print "found", test_string
```

But I have a distinct feeling that I misunderstand the question.

Comment: what if i have test_string in a dictionary and to_search in a different dictionary. would my code be similar?

Comment: Using `in` with strings can be dangerous, because it's hard to know whether there might be some substring which looks like `'BA177T'` or `'A177T2'`.  If what you're searching for is wordlike (i.e. bracketed by whitespace), you're better off using `.split()` and then using `in` on the list.

Comment: @ChadD Rewrite your question to only have the input data, your example code, and what you want to get out of the data. that should clarify things

Comment: @DSM where would i use .split()?